# PHP : DOM Parser to iterate html code

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

```
<div class="reviews-summary__stats">
                <div class="reviews-summary">
                    <p class="reviews-title">A</p>
                    <ul class="rating">
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item "></li>
                        <li class="rating__item "></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews-summary">
                    <p class="reviews-title">B</p>
                    <ul class="rating">
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item "></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews-summary">
                    <p class="reviews-title">C</p>
                    <ul class="rating">
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
                        <li class="rating__item "></li>
                        <li class="rating__item "></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
</div>
```

i want to iterate over each **div.reviews-summary** but i am not getting to next **p.reviews-title** and **li.rating__item rating__rated** tag, and also count the `li.rating__item rating__rated`  for separate `p` tag, and display integer value of no of **li.rating__item rating__rated** that are exist in `ul`.and also check if `A` exist then display `li.rating__item rating__rated` of A.

```
<?php
    include("simple_html_dom.php");
    $obj = new simple_html_dom();

    foreach ($obj->find('div[class=reviews-summary]') as $factor)
    {
        $item = $factor->find('p[class=reviews-title]')->plaintext;

        if(trim($item) == 'A')
        { 
            $a = $factor->find('li[class=rating__item rating__rated]',0)->plaintext;
        }
        if(trim($item) == 'B')
        { 
            $b = $factor->find('li[class=rating__item rating__rated]',0)->plaintext;
        }
        if(trim($item) == 'C')
        { 
            $c = $factor->find('li[class=rating__item rating__rated]',0)->plaintext;
        }
        $final_array['overalldata'] = array
        (
            'a' => $a,   // no of A have <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li> 
            'b' => $b,
            'c' => $c,
        );
    }
    print_r($final_array);
    die;
?>
```

i want display like this type of output, 
 **Array
(
    [overalldata] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4

            [b] => 5

            [c] => 4

        )
)**

Any body having any idea please help to sort it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is (hopefully) slightly wrong.  You have three sets of `<p class="reviews-title">C</p>`, so all items are 'C'.  But if you replace them with A and B, you could use the following code.

All it does is to store a count of the number of  `li[class=rating__item rating__rated]` items under the index of the lower case version of the `<p class="reviews-title">` value...

```
$final_array=array();
foreach ($obj->find('div[class=reviews-summary]') as $factor)
{
    $item = trim($factor->find('p[class=reviews-title]',0)->plaintext);
    $factor = count($factor->find('li[class=rating__item rating__rated]'));
    if($item == 'A')
    {
        $final_array['overalldata']['a']= $factor;
    }
    if($item == 'B')
    {
        $final_array['overalldata']['b']= $factor;
    }
    if($item == 'C')
    {
        $final_array['overalldata']['c']= $factor;
    }
}
print_r($final_array);
```

I've updated the HTML to (so just replacing the A and B)...

```
<div class="reviews-summary__stats">
    <div class="reviews-summary">
        <p class="reviews-title">A</p>
        <ul class="rating">
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="reviews-summary">
        <p class="reviews-title">B</p>
        <ul class="rating">
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="reviews-summary">
        <p class="reviews-title">C</p>
        <ul class="rating">
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item rating__rated"></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
            <li class="rating__item "></li>
        </ul>
    </div>     
</div>
```

This outputs...

```
Array
(
    [overalldata] => Array
        (
            [a] => 3
            [b] => 4
            [c] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: look output,all have separate print, so do not print all in one

Comment: I've added the output to the answer, it looks just like the output in the question.

Comment: it look like this type of answer                                                                             Array ( [overalldata] => Array ( [] => 4 ) ) ,and look i edit html so try

Comment: Can you change `[strtolower($item)]` to `[$item]` and see what that does.

Comment: If the last bit gives you some output, try changing `strtolower` to `mb_strtolower` as this should work with different string encoding.

Comment: I've changed the code to use the previous method if identifying the elements A,B and C.

Comment: small kind of right answer, bt in array all value must same output= 4        Array
(
    [overalldata] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4    
            [b] => 4    
            [c] => 4   
        )
)   there  [b] => 5  , bt display  [b] => 4   that's how ??

Comment: With your sample data it shows `Array
(
    [overalldata] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 5
            [c] => 4
        )

)`

Comment: yes but Array ( [overalldata] => Array ( [a] => 4 [b] => 5 [c] => 4 ) ) this not shown,it show like as  Array
(
    [overalldata] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4    
            [b] => 4    
            [c] => 4   
        )
) so,it not correct

Comment: hello,Nigel Ren give any idea please ,

Comment: I have checked it and run it several times, it always gives me (with your test data above ) - `Array
(
    [overalldata] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 5
            [c] => 4
        )

)`, so unless there is some other data, I can't help.

Comment: can u update  that php code , u are created please:)